# What Closure is Dart NoSuchMethodError output referring to?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app (v1.2.1) and I'm trying to debug an error that I cannot reproduce in debug mode. I know the root cause is calling forEach on a null object, but I'm trying to find which forEach in my code it's referring to. I don't understand the "Tried calling" portion of the error message and can't find any details on it in the Dart NoSuchMethodError class documentation. This is the error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (CustomObject) => Null)
```

Does that error mean it occurred on a forEach that had the format forEach((CustomObject) => {method body}), or a forEach that is inside of a closure with the format (CustomObject) => {method body}?

E.g. Would it be something like this:

```
methodOne(List<CustomObject> fakeObjects) {
 fakeObjects.forEach((CustomObject thingOne) {
   print(thingOne);
 });
}
```

or something like this:

```
methodTwo(CustomObject thingOne) {
  ...some code
  listOfItems.forEach((String item) {
    print(item);
  });
}
```

Comment: fakeObjects or listOfItems is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduce this bug. 
Your fakeObjects is null, please see the following code snippet and picture

```
List<String> fakeObjects = null;
    fakeObjects.forEach((String thingOne) {
      print(thingOne);
    });
```

[image]

Output

```
The method 'forEach' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (String) => Null)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So the "Tried Calling" line is describing the full parameter that was called and the closure it's referring to is the closure that is part of that line, as opposed to the closure the error occurred in. I really wish it would just print the stack trace!